# Coding a Mac OS X terminal emulator?

Tags: cocoa, macos, terminal-emulator

I'd like to create a terminal emulator for Mac OS X. The problem is: I have no idea where to start. Can I just use a whole bunch of NSTasks? Or do I have to read through tons of source code for programs like xterm, urxvt, etc?
I don't want a lot of customizability (= no config file parsing), nor complex features, and I'm only gonna use bash as the shell.

Thanks for answers!

-Mike

Answer (score 5):

I'd check out Visor: http://code.google.com/p/blacktree-visor/  It's a Quake-style terminal that slides up and down from the edge of the screen.

iTerm (http://iterm.sourceforge.net/) would also be a good project to look at (perhaps even better than Visor).

Comment: +1 for a sick open source project that I might just use in the near future :D

Comment: Didn't know Visor. Using it for 5 minutes now. Its great!

Comment: Visor's cool, but it's just the OS Terminal.app with its UI hacked a bit... no code there.

Answer (score 1):

As Dave said, iTerm is probably the best place to start.

As for others, xterm/urxvt might not be the easiest thing to read for this, since they'll be mapping between VT100 and Xlib, which is kind of low-level.  An implementation that might be easier to read is [VTE terminal](http://library.gnome.org/devel/vte/unstable/VteTerminal.html), which GNOME uses, since it'll be mapping between VT100 and GLib/GTK+, which is probably a lot closer to what Mac OS X provides.

Good luck!